# Delete file after interrupting download.file

Tags: r

I was wondering if it's possible to delete a file that was being downloaded via `download.file()` when the user interrupted the download operations (using the red STOP button in Rstudio or CTRL-C in R running on the command prompt). For example, the following code runs fine:

```r
# set a tempfile
(my_destfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".osm.pbf"))
#> [1] "C:\\Users\\Utente\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmpuqeido\\file34f44a736417.osm.pbf"

# set url + download
my_url <- "https://download.openstreetmap.fr/extracts/africa/benin-latest.osm.pbf"
download.file(
  url = my_url, 
  destfile = my_destfile, 
  mode = "wb"
)

# check 
list.files(tempdir())
#> [1] "file34f41f54244d"         "file34f4295e1136"        
#> [3] "file34f44a736417.osm.pbf" "file34f49e0136d"

# remove
file.remove(my_destfile)
#> [1] TRUE

# check 
list.files(tempdir())
#> [1] "file34f41f54244d" "file34f4295e1136" "file34f49e0136d"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

while when I run the following code and interrupt the download process:

```r
# set a tempfile
(my_destfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".osm.pbf"))

# set url + download
my_url <- "https://download.openstreetmap.fr/extracts/africa/benin-latest.osm.pbf"
download.file(
  url = my_url, 
  destfile = my_destfile, 
  mode = "wb"
)

# check 
list.files(tempdir())

# remove
file.remove(my_destfile)

# check 
list.files(tempdir())
```

I get the following warning message (and the file is not removed):

```
> file.remove(my_destfile)
[1] FALSE
Warning message:
In file.remove(my_destfile) :
  cannot remove file 'C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpEDMkAN\file272c63c21783.osm.pbf', reason 'Permission denied'
```

I get the same behaviour with `unlink()` instead of `file.remove()`.

**CONTEXT:** I'm working on an R package to download data from online databases and I would like to remove the files that are only partially downloaded.

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I add the Session Info:

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> - Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64              
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32             
#>  ui       RTerm                       
#>  language en                          
#>  collate  English_United Kingdom.1252 
#>  ctype    English_United Kingdom.1252 
#>  tz       Europe/Berlin               
#>  date     2021-08-02
```

Comment: On my mac Intel, it is normally removed even if the process is interrupted. Please use https instead of http, especially here as other people will run this code.

Comment: Thanks for the fix and for the comment